# Receiving SMS using Broadcast worked few days ago but now its not working

Tags: android

When I searched what is missing then I found priority is not given. After giving priority also it is not working... is there any change or update in coding?

AndroidManifest.xml, I have used receiver inside application tag and permission outside application tag (not in activity).

I have asked READ_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS, SEND_SMS permissions at the beginning.

The code was working fine. Don't know how and why it is not working...
Looking for positive response soon. Thank you.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />


 <receiver
        android:name=".helpers.MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">

        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = MyBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String SMS = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
public static final String pdu_type = "pdus";

String strSender = "";
String strMessage = "";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    /*This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving*/

    Toast.makeText(context, "sms received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS)) {
        // Get the SMS message.
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        // Retrieve the SMS message received.
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get(pdu_type);
        SmsMessage[] msgs;
        if (pdus != null) {
            // Fill the msgs array.
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                // Check Android version and use appropriate createFromPdu.
                // If Android version M or newer:
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    String format = bundle.getString("format");
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], format);
                } else {
                    // If Android version L or older:
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                }
                // Build the message to show.
                strSender = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                strMessage = msgs[i].getMessageBody();

                Toast.makeText(context, "onReceive: sender number is: " + strSender, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add in manifest and check
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

or you can also check the register and unregister flow in which action with name or intent filter in oncreate and ondestroy,,,,,please correct it if you are missing here.

Also please check SMS format is changed or with your validation and parsing problem

Also check the SMS service problem like twillio or other trial or paid or API problem inside your backend side

Try this way may help you