# Can not load google maps when app installed from store

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

i have an android application created with some apis such as push notifications, google maps, sms retriever, and some other apis.

when i build the signed apk and i copie it to my phone and i install it directly, everything is fine, the otp sms is automatically detected, the maps is shown and i have no problem.

but when i publish the same file in the store, and i download and install the app, the sms is not automatically detected, and the maps cannot be shown.

i dont know why this can happen, it is the same signed file, why everything is fine when i install it directly and i have these problems when i download it from the store?

normally these problems occur when i use a debug sha1 in production, but no i use a production sha1 which is also the same in the console .. and like i said, the application is signed.

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Using Play App Signing
If you've published your app using Play App Signing, a requirement when using Android App Bundle, you can get your SHA-1 from the Google Play Console on the Release > Setup > App Integrity page.

Also try this below way may help you

Please Try to get the SHA1 from release keystore using the command prompt and then update this SHA1 to Google map cloud console with package name where you have added debug SHA1

keytool -list -v -keystore keystore_name -alias alias_name

Like on command prompt try this way according to you folder and keytool folder

**In Windows**

```
c:\bin> keytool -list -v -keystore D:\Users\project\keystore.jks -alias test1234
```

**In Ubuntu**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /home/administrator/keystorepath/keystore.jks -alias testalias
```

Enter keystore password:  123

Comment: thank you for your answer. yes i m already using the same SHA-1 in the Google Play Console.. the problem is when i install the signed apk file everything is OK, but when i publish the same file to the console and i install it from the store i get these 2 problems.. i also noticed that the apk size is 5.6Mo, but in the store it is 4.5Mo .. although it is the same version

Comment: For SMS problem please try just this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/68468822/4042384   and try to check original and resigned apk from artifact on console

Comment: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2226

Comment: the problem is not in my code or my config in console, I did all the necessary configuration in the console with the production SHA-1 that I generated using the command prompt, and which is also the same in the console. the last week i requested a signin key updgrade because i lost my store file, and google helped me to reset it, and i reconfigured my project with the new certificate. as I told you, the signed apk works fine when I install it directly without going through the store. I think there is a conflict somewhere

Comment: If your signed apk is working fine then it should be work same on install app from play store, , it may be you have selected play app signing features so you need to copy the sha1 key after publish success to your map console. So Please ask the Google play support team it may help you

Comment: Yes that's what i did.. i m waiting for their answer.. thank you anyway